# What is the name of a mathematical object which transforms an input number into an output number?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

What 
is the name of a mathematical object which transforms an input number into an output number?

Comment: Do you mean "function"?

Comment: That is, oddly enough, a "numerical transformation"!  (It is a "function" if and only if each input correspond go a unique output.)

Comment: A map $f\colon K\rightarrow K$, where $K$ is a field (or a domain), containing "numbers". Otherwise you don't have numbers. Instead of "map" you can say "transformation", since you said "which transforms a given number..."